# disable scroll to div

Tags: html, css

Hi i have a little problem, need to disable scroll to the div after clicking on link that targets left div.

```
<div class="kafelki">
<div class="kafelki-img">
<div class="target">
<div id="m1">dasdasdasd m1</div>
<div id="m2">dadasdasdasd m2</div>
<div id="m3">sdasdasds m3</div>
<div id="m4">dasdasdsad m4</div>
<div id="m5">dasdasd m5</div>
<div id="m6">asdasdad m6</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="kafelki-lista">
<ul>
<li><a href="#m1">dla firm produkcyjno-usługowo-handlowych</a></li>
<li><a href="#m2">dla biur rachunkowych</a></li>
<li><a href="#m3">dla sklepów</a></li>
<li><a href="#m4">dla moteli i gastronomii</a></li>
<li><a href="#m5">dla lekarzy i prawników</a></li>
<li><a href="#m6">dla jednostek publicznych</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/guzior/exMx8/)

Comment: vertical or horizontal

Comment: Why are you targeting it then?

Comment: What is your question ? Disable scroll on which div ? Horizontal or vertical scroll ?

Comment: i'm targeting for example #m1 and target the #m1 in div with class target and when you click on link from list it scrolls down

Comment: If you want to stop the scroll then just don't target it. Why are you targeting it if you don't want this to happen?

Comment: i need to display an image on the left after clicking the link but if it is not possible to disable this thing than maybe it will be ok after adding images when i get them

Comment: Don't specify width in px for .kafelki  and try to fix the position to absolute

Comment: Please review my answer

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do what you want in `jQuery` I believe

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

This will probably do what you want, however it would target all the `a` tags, it would be better for you to apply a class on the one's you don't want to make scroll. You would need to change the line above from:

```
$('a').on('click', function(e){
```

to

```
$('.className').on('click', function(e){
```

and your modified HTML would be something like

```
<li><a class="className" href="#m3">dla sklepów</a></li>
```

Comment: it blocks whole thing, i think maybe it will be better to make a slider there with controls like i have on right but i have no idea how ;/

Comment: what do you mean it blocks the whole thing? did you try the version where you add a class to the ones you want to stop the scrolling on?

Comment: yes i tried with the class but after clicking a link doesn't display anything in targeted div

Comment: after clicking the link from list in right div, it should look like a slider controled from that list